# How could I Deserialize this xml to class

Tags: c#

I want to deserialize a XML file to a class but it fails. Please Help!!

XML file like this:

```
<messages>
   <message name="a">
  <field name="ab"/>
  <field name="ab1"/>
  <field name="ab2"/>
 </message>
   <message name="b">
      <field name="bc"/>
      <group name="ab">
         <field name="ab"/>
         <field name="ab1"/>
         <field name="ab2"/>
          <group name="ab">
             <field name="4"/>
           </group>
      </group>
       <field />
       ....

    </message>
</messages>
```

this is just a demo.The reality is a "message" include several "field" and "group",and the group include several field and also group!!!
It is random not constant.

I have try this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(GroupInMsg))]
[XmlType("field")]
public class FieldBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

}

[XmlType("message")]
public class Message
{
    public Message()
    {

    }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }



    public FieldBase[] Fields { get; set; }
}


public class GroupInMsg : FieldBase
{
    public GroupInMsg()
    {

    }

    //[XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(FieldBase))]
    //[XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(GroupInMsg))]
    public FieldBase[] Fields { get; set; }
}
```

My final target is to Deserialize the **Quickfix** Something like this

```
<messages>
    <message name="Heartbeat" msgtype="0" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="TestReqID" required="N"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Logon" msgtype="A" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="EncryptMethod" required="Y"/>
      <field name="HeartBtInt" required="Y"/>
      <field name="RawDataLength" required="N"/>
      <field name="RawData" required="N"/>
      <field name="ResetSeqNumFlag" required="N"/>
      <field name="MaxMessageSize" required="N"/>
      <group name="NoMsgTypes" required="N">
        <field name="RefMsgType" required="N"/>
        <field name="MsgDirection" required="N"/>
      </group>
    </message>
    <message name="TestRequest" msgtype="1" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="TestReqID" required="Y"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ResendRequest" msgtype="2" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="BeginSeqNo" required="Y"/>
      <field name="EndSeqNo" required="Y"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Reject" msgtype="3" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="RefSeqNum" required="Y"/>
      <field name="RefTagID" required="N"/>
      <field name="RefMsgType" required="N"/>
      <field name="SessionRejectReason" required="N"/>
      <field name="Text" required="N"/>
      <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N"/>
      <field name="EncodedText" required="N"/>
    </message>
    <message name="SequenceReset" msgtype="4" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="GapFillFlag" required="N"/>
      <field name="NewSeqNo" required="Y"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Logout" msgtype="5" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="Text" required="N"/>
      <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N"/>
      <field name="EncodedText" required="N"/>
    </message>
......
```

many messges.many feild and group in messge.And also many group and field in group!!!

Forgive me!Thanks!

Comment: Can you also provide your class structure?

Comment: Regarding deserialization there is a good example in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: "_but it fails_"  tells us nothing.  In what way does it fail?  Show the code you used to deserialize the xml.

Comment: I know the biasic Deserialize.but this is nested

Answer (score 0):

@ppz.whenever you want to ask something help or solution On StackOverflow community. I mean what you expect or facing some error You have to describe a proper way.so that the community will understand and provide a better solution asap.
You can refer below code
As per XML data you provided to us.
  **Model**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "field")]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "message")]
    public class Message
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "field")]
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "group")]
        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "group")]
    public class Group
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "field")]
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "messages")]
    public class Messages
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "message")]
        public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
    }
```

And you deserialize your XML like below

```
string path = string.Empty;
            string xmlInputData = string.Empty;
            try
            {
               path = "XML file path";
                xmlInputData = File.ReadAllText(path);
                Messages _Messages = Deserialize<Messages>(xmlInputData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
        public static T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }
```

I hope It helps you. Thank you..!

Comment: Thank you very much!Forgive me for the unclear question.The reality is a "message" include several "field" and "group",and the group include several field and also group!!! It is random not constant.

Comment: could you please read the question. I edit it. Thanks again!!